# FastApi | как добавить в документацию кастомный обработчик ошибок

Tags: python, fastapi

У меня в приложении переопределен стандартный обработчик ошибок

```py
# exceptions
@app.exception_handler(HTTPException)
async def http_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: HTTPException) -> OnErrorResModel:
  return JSONResponse(
      status_code=exc.status_code,
      content={'result': 'error', 'error': exc.detail, 'time': datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")}
    )
```

Так вот, хотелось бы, чтобы в автоматической документации у каждого маршрута, помимо упешного результата и ошибки валидации, была и "стандартная" ошибка

(1 картинка - как сейчас, 2 - как надо)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: а вот так надо]

Answer (score 0):

```
# default on_error response
class OnErrorResModel(BaseModel):
  result: Literal['error']
  error: str
  time: str
```

```
app = FastAPI(responses={400: {'model': OnErrorResModel}})
```

Если что, такое можно и с роутером и с отдельными маршрутами сделать